# Positioning tooltip in dimplejs barchart

Tags: dimple.js

Is there a way to place the tooltip in the bar chart instead of hovering to the left on a dimplejs bar chart? I would like to place it in inline with the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial [here](http://annapawlicka.com/pretty-charts-with-dimple-js/) should help to change the position of the tooltip.